# What is the application launched by canopy when running a python file with matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib, canopy

What is the application used by canopy when running a python file?

This application opens in a new window when using matplotlib. See screenshot below.

Is it possible to use this application directly without canopy?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matplotlib opens a displays a figure that has been rendered by the selected [backend](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend) when you call [show](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.show). You can find out what backend is in use with:

```
matplotlib.get_backend()
```

and set the backend by updating the [matplotlibrc](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html#customizing-matplotlib) file or with:

```
matplotlib.use('PS')
```

`matplotlib.use()` has only effect if called before `pylab`, `matplotlib.pyplot`, or `matplotlib.backends` is imported for the first time.

Running the same Python program with the same backend in an environment other than Canopy will display the same figure.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Please consider updating it with the following: "`matplotlib.use()` has only effect if called **before** `pylab`, `matplotlib.pyplot`, or `matplotlib.backends` is imported for the first time."

Answer (score 0):

The application that displays the plot is Python (in particular Canopy User Python), using the Matplotlib library with a Qt backend. To run this from outside Canopy:

1) Ensure that Canopy User Python is your default Python; the simplest way is to open a "Canopy Command Prompt Window" from the Start Menu, or see https://support.enthought.com/entries/23646538-Make-Canopy-User-Python-be-your-default-Python).

2) Run the following commands:

`set ets_toolkit=qt4
python my_scripty.py`